# JPA ManytoMany returns only first object in Spring

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Hi I have below code which does return all books and related publisher info. But i see only first result get first and third objects just has bookPublishers entries but the 2nd object doesn't have nested object.

Is something wrong with JPA or JSON serialization?
Is something needs to be altered for the serialization purpose?

**Solutions Tried:**

Have tried removing JsonIdentityInfo annotation from both Book & Publisher but that results in Infinite recursion.

**Code:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",
    scope = Book.class)
public class Book implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers = new HashSet<>();

  public Book(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id",
    scope = Publisher.class)
public class Publisher implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher")
  private Set<BookPublisher> bookPublishers = new HashSet<>();

  public Publisher(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_publisher")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.bookId", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.publisherId",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id"))})
public class BookPublisher implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private BookPublisherId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("bookId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  private Book book;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("publisherId")
  @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id")
  private Publisher publisher;

  @Column(name = "published_date")
  private Date publishedDate;

  public BookPublisher(Book book, Publisher publisher, Date publishedDate) {
    this.id = new BookPublisherId(book.getId(), publisher.getId());
    this.book = book;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
  }

}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class BookPublisherId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "book_id")
  private Integer bookId;

  @Column(name = "publisher_id")
  private Integer publisherId;

}
```

**Expected:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Book1",
    "bookPublishers": [
      {
        "publisher": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Pub2"
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      },
      {
        "publisher": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Pub1"
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Book2",
    "bookPublishers": [
      {
        "publisher": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Pub1"
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      },
      {
        "publisher": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Pub2"
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Book3",
    "bookPublishers": [
      {
        "publisher": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Pub3"
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Actual:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Book1",
    "bookPublishers": [
      {
        "id": {
          "bookId": 1,
          "publisherId": 2
        },
        "book": 1,
        "publisher": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Pub2",
          "bookPublishers": [
            {
              "bookId": 1,
              "publisherId": 2
            },
            {
              "id": {
                "bookId": 2,
                "publisherId": 2
              },
              "book": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Book2",
                "bookPublishers": [
                  {
                    "id": {
                      "bookId": 2,
                      "publisherId": 1
                    },
                    "book": 2,
                    "publisher": {
                      "id": 1,
                      "name": "Pub1",
                      "bookPublishers": [
                        {
                          "bookId": 2,
                          "publisherId": 1
                        },
                        {
                          "id": {
                            "bookId": 1,
                            "publisherId": 1
                          },
                          "book": 1,
                          "publisher": 1,
                          "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
                  },
                  {
                    "bookId": 2,
                    "publisherId": 2
                  }
                ]
              },
              "publisher": 2,
              "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
            }
          ]
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      },
      {
        "bookId": 1,
        "publisherId": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  2,                 <<<<<<<<<<<<<- Here whole object itself missing???
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Book3",
    "bookPublishers": [
      {
        "id": {
          "bookId": 3,
          "publisherId": 3
        },
        "book": 3,
        "publisher": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Pub3",
          "bookPublishers": [
            {
              "bookId": 3,
              "publisherId": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "publishedDate": "2021-06-06T14:42:30.754+00:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**DB Results:**

```
select * from book;
select * from publisher;
select * from book_publisher;

id  name
1   Book1
2   Book2
3   Book3

id  name
1   Pub1
2   Pub2
3   Pub3

book_id publisher_id    published_date
1         1             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
1         2             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
2         1             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
2         2             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
3         3             2021-06-06 20:12:30.7540000
```

**Solutions Tried But still same Problem: Added equals/hashcode for all class**
Please find the implementations for each class:

```
Book:
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;
    Book Book = (Book) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, Book.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name);
  }

Publisher:
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;

    Publisher Publisher = (Publisher) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, Publisher.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name);
  }

BookPublisher:
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;

    BookPublisher that = (BookPublisher) o;
    return Objects.equals(book, that.book) && Objects.equals(publisher, that.publisher);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(book, publisher);
  }

BookPublisherId:
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;

    BookPublisherId that = (BookPublisherId) o;
    return Objects.equals(bookId, that.bookId) && Objects.equals(publisherId, that.publisherId);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(bookId, publisherId);
  }
```

**Output Query generated for bookRepository.findAll():**

```
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_0_, book0_.name as name2_0_ from Book book0_
Hibernate: select bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_0_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_1_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_1_, bookpublis0_.published_date as publishe3_1_1_, publisher1_.id as id1_3_2_, publisher1_.name as name2_3_2_ from book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Publisher publisher1_ on bookpublis0_.publisher_id=publisher1_.id where bookpublis0_.book_id=?
Hibernate: select bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_1_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_1_, bookpublis0_.published_date as publishe3_1_1_, book1_.id as id1_0_2_, book1_.name as name2_0_2_ from book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Book book1_ on bookpublis0_.book_id=book1_.id where bookpublis0_.publisher_id=?
Hibernate: select bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_0_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_1_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_1_, bookpublis0_.published_date as publishe3_1_1_, publisher1_.id as id1_3_2_, publisher1_.name as name2_3_2_ from book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Publisher publisher1_ on bookpublis0_.publisher_id=publisher1_.id where bookpublis0_.book_id=?
Hibernate: select bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_1_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_1_, bookpublis0_.published_date as publishe3_1_1_, book1_.id as id1_0_2_, book1_.name as name2_0_2_ from book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Book book1_ on bookpublis0_.book_id=book1_.id where bookpublis0_.publisher_id=?
Hibernate: select bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_0_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_1_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_1_, bookpublis0_.published_date as publishe3_1_1_, publisher1_.id as id1_3_2_, publisher1_.name as name2_3_2_ from book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Publisher publisher1_ on bookpublis0_.publisher_id=publisher1_.id where bookpublis0_.book_id=?
Hibernate: select bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_0_, bookpublis0_.book_id as book_id1_1_1_, bookpublis0_.publisher_id as publishe2_1_1_, bookpublis0_.published_date as publishe3_1_1_, book1_.id as id1_0_2_, book1_.name as name2_0_2_ from book_publisher bookpublis0_ inner join Book book1_ on bookpublis0_.book_id=book1_.id where bookpublis0_.publisher_id=?
```

Comment: Do you have all your foreign keys present in DB? That might explain why you only have some records.

Comment: @Pilpo yes it does have results and i have attached db results also for all the tables in the question.

Comment: An other point is that you didn't write explicity equals/hashcode which are necessary because you are using Set<> (and also embbeded id) (Hibernate need them to calculate the hash according to your object and not according to the id)

Comment: @Pilpo Does adding annotation Data from lambok doesn't help in '@EqualsAndHashCode' also.... or should i need to place manual Equals & Hashcode implementation?

Comment: I don't know enough Lombok to talk about it. First, you should try to add them manually. If success, them test with Lombok :)

Comment: So should i need to add equals/hashcode in all class or only in BookPublisher?

Comment: Yes, you should get into the habit of always addind equals/hashcode in all of your entities.

Comment: @Pilpo have removed all lambok thing and added equals and hashcode implementation for all classes. But results is same as actual shown above.

Comment: Do your equals/hashcode use all the fields for each class? You should also check the SQL query generated by Hibernate to see if it is ok.

Comment: @Pilpo yes have attached equals/hashcode implementations for all classes & query logs in above question. let me know if i made any mistakes?

Comment: You are missing the field ID in Book/publisher. In Book you are missing the field bookPublishers. Be sure to add all the fields.

Comment: @Pilpo 1. added ID in book & publisher object. Not working & Same result, 2. added bookPublishers field also in equals & hash but creates a unlimited query. Not working

Comment: It creates an unlimited query because you have a recursion. Remove the recursion. If after that it's still not working, maybe try to handle the OneToMany this way https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many#models instead of using an embedded key. If it's still not working after, I don't know...

Comment: @Pilpo The unlimited jointable query executes after adding bookPublishers in equals/hashcode. Also i would like to have to implement extra columns in relation table so trying with embedded key.